# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '(MyReactiveVarName' of null

Tags: meteor

Could you tell me why I can not work with Reactive Var in timeout function? I tried to change the Reactive Var after 1 sec timeout, but it is impossible, though I work whith the same template all the time:

```
  Template.instance().taskNumRV.set(0); => works well
  setTimeout(function() { 
  Template.instance().taskNumRV.set(2); => Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'taskNumRV' of null
  }, 1000);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Im not sure since its been a while i dont use Blaze, but i guess you are calling this code inside a helper right?

Comment: I called this code inside an Event Handler. Thank you for your interest in helping me, the next answer works perfectly!

Comment: if you call this inside an event handler why dont just
`Template.xxxx.events({
  'event': (event, template) => {
setTimeout(function () { 
  template.taskNumRV.set(2);
}, 1000);
}
})`, you have the 2 args `event` and `template` on the event handlers so you dont need to reference them using `Template.instance()`

Comment: Thank you, I would like to try to simplify my code with your recommendation. But in this case does it will be possible to work with that RV (reactivVar) in other parts of the code (with that Tamplate but outside that Event Handler - for example, in some helpers of that Template)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your callback function is called, `Template.instance()` no longer refers to the proper template instance. To fix this assign `Template.instance()` to a local variable, then use that variable in your `setTimeout` callback. For example:

```
const instance = Template.instance();
setTimeout(function () { 
  instance.taskNumRV.set(2);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your recommendation works perfectly!